# Android emulator cannot send or receive http messages between localhost server and flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, http, graphql, android-emulator

I am not able to send or receive http messages between my localhost server and my flutter app using the android emulator. Don't think that this has anything to do with it - but I am using graphql for the messages. For the record: it must be an emulator problem as the webapp (which is also running on localhost) works. So generally it works well.

I tried the following:

- using `'http://10.0.2.2:3000/appdata/apiv2'`
- using `'http://localhost:3000/appdata/apiv2'` with `adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000`
- Putting Firewall off
- Trying older and newer android versions
- Desperately playing around with the Extended Controls -> Settings -> Proxy using android studio http proxy settings, or don't use proxy and also manual proxy configuration (maybe i did not find the right proxy configuration here, but actually I don't think that proxy configurations can help me - maybe I am wrong)

I am desperated and need your help :) what else can I do? All the other stackoverflow questions with that question are just happy using the `10.0.2.2` IP address.

Comment: Android 11+? usesClearTextTraffic="true" ?

Comment: is that a flag that i can set somewhere?

Comment: Yes indeed. In application tag of manifest file.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that - tried it but still doesnt work unfortunately :/

Comment: Can a browser on the emulator reach your server?

Comment: No also not unfortunately

Comment: Well than it has nothing to do with your app.

Comment: `the webapp (which is also running on localhost) works. ` If you have another computer in the lan then try webapp from there. And browsers on that computer. Try another emulator.